# Flashplaver for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to install the flashplayer plugin in the three steps shown on http://www.itworld.com/software/415657/install-adobe-flash-plugin-ubuntu-1404
but get the following message:
 Package adobe-flashplugin is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source. E: Package 'adobe-flashplugin' has no installation cadidate.

I'm a total noobie when it comes to Linux, and I didn't bother at all with the DOS when using Windows OS, so what does this exactly mean? Can I install flash from somewhere else?

Jannike

Comment: Oh, sorry for the typo. Ubuntu it is, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install flashplayer plugin in ubuntu please type in the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: I followed your instructions and the downloading seems to be doing quite well, though in the end-user lincense the OK-button is not a button, so I can't agree to anything. :| BUT most important: the plugin is working! Whoopee! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: How do I now make this problem "solved"?

Comment: If my solution worked all you have to do is click the tick button under the vote up and vote down buttons. Also the solution to select ok under the EULA is by pressing TAB button.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to install Flash Player in Lubuntu 10.0, Lubuntu 13 and Ubuntu 12, following the steps indicated from the "original" [flash player download page](http://get.adobe.com/es/flashplayer/otherversions/), with the .tar.gz download

Just download it, extract, and follow the steps.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon karel has already answered your question appropriately. however if you want some more insights have a look onto http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/06/install-pepper-flash-chromium-ubuntu-14-04